# call-back behavior in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, callback

My question is more towards the design pattern to use for my implementation. I have the code written as follows -

X-Service.java

```
handler.setListeners(new HttpResponseHandler.conListers() {

    @Override
    public void success() {

    }

});
```

HttpResponseHandler

```
protected conListers conListener;
public interface conListers {
    public void success();
}

public void conListers(conListers listener) {
    this.conListers = listener;
}
```

So now my problem is I can use this technique If I had just one type of success function. To be more clear I have multiple services where success method have different signature like --

```
public void success(String x);
public void success(HashMap y, Integer z);
```

I do not want to put all the methods in the interface, as I will have to implement them in all the services. I need a way in which I can just implement the success method I want.

Comment: might work with generics depending on your usecase.

Comment: I also might need to pass multiple parameters ...

Comment: You might need multiple interfaces then :)

Comment: @Fox You can always wrap the multiple parameters into a single object. I.e. is pretty much what .NET does with `EventHandler` delegates.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the interface using a generic type declaration:

```
public interface conListers<E> {
    public void success(E value);
}
```

Alternatively, if you need a variable number of arguments of the same type then you can use:

```
public interface conListers<E> {
    public void success(E... value);
}
```

If you need a fixed number of arguments then you can just test the length of the `value` argument in the definition of `success()` in the implementing class.

However, I can't think of any pattern you can use to allow `success()` to take a variably fixed number of different typed arguments unless you use `Object` but that then brings its own issues (like having to type check all the arguments within the implementing class):

```
public interface conListers {
    public void success(Object... value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command pattern in this scenario, basically the `conListener` will be your command. You'll have as many conListeners implementations as your services.

Example:

```
public class conListenersA implements conListener{
    protected Service serviceA;
    public void success(){
        serviceA.success(arg1);//the method has  arguments
    }
}

public class conListenersB implements conListener{
    protected Service serviceB;
    public void success(){
        serviceB.success(arg1,arg2);//the method has 2 arguments
    }
}
```

The advantage is that whenever you need to execute a `conListener` you call will be "uniform", as simple as `conListener.success()`

Comment: Very elegant solution! IMHO, it seems the most atractive among others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with most general Java class `Object` as a parameter and use varargs:

```
public interface conListers {
    public void success(Object... arguments);
}
```

Inside implementation you'll have to figure out object types and the number of arguments, but you'll have a clean interface for your functions.

Another approach is to define a class that holds all of your arguments that you are planning to send on a success, and then inside implemented success methods get parameters that you really need.